# Symfony datatable server side pagination

Tags: symfony, datatable, server-side

I try to add server side processing for datatable in symfony 2.7.

I have my js :

```
{% set jsonOptionsDataBases %}
{
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "{{  path("surveillance_bo_dossier_home_tableau",{"type": 0, "client":client}) }}",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
    "pageLength": 100,
    "columns": [
        {data: "client"},
        {data: "dossier"},
        {data: "type"},
        {data: "dateD"},
        {data: "dateF"},
        {data: "analyse"},
        {data: "frequence"},
        {data: "cc"},
        {data: "dateR"},
        {data: "action"},
        {data: "jur"},
        {data: "isActif"},
    ]
{% endset %}
{{ macro_datatables.datatablesInit('dossiers','dossiers',jsonOptionsDataBases,a_colWithSelect,a_colWithDate,a_colEmpty, a_colWithSelectOtherColumn, a_colWithDateUs)  }}
```

Macro generates my table.

My controller :

```
$users = $Surv->getRepository('t:s\Dossier')->ServerSide($filters, 0, $length);
$output = array(
        'data' => array(),
        'recordsFiltered' => $I_nbResultatsTotal,
        'recordsTotal' => $I_nbResultatsTotal,
    );
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($users as $O_dossier) {
        $I_idDossier = $O_dossier->getId();
        $I_idRapportLast = 0;
        $output['data'][] = [
            'client' => 1,
            'dossier' => 1,
            'type' => 1,
            'dateD' => 1,
            'dateF' =>1,
            'analyse' => 1,
            'frequence' => 1,
            'dateR' => 1,
            'action' => 1,
            'cc' =>1,
            'jur' => 1,
            'isActif' => 1
        ];
        $I_nbResultatsTotal++;
    }

    return new Response(json_encode($output), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
```

and the function serverside :

```
public function ServerSide($data, $page = 0, $max = NULL, $getResult = true)
{



    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = isset($data['query']) && $data['query']?$data['query']:null;

    $qb
        ->select('u')
        ->from('t:s\Dossier', 'u')
    ;

    if ($query) {
        $qb
            ->andWhere('u.name like :query')
            ->setParameter('query', "%".$query."%")
        ;
    }

    if ($max) {
        $preparedQuery = $qb->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults($max)
            ->setFirstResult($page * $max)
        ;
    } else {
        $preparedQuery = $qb->getQuery();
    }

    return $getResult?$preparedQuery->getResult():$preparedQuery;
}
```

I have 137 results, so with the option "pagelength" i have two page, problem is the count of result, i have 137 result on one page, in my first page i need 100 results, and i d'ont understand why i have all the results here.

Comment: The line `$users ($A_listeDossiers as $O_dossier) {` in your controller looks wrong to me (it should be foreach, right?). Are you sure your code is even running without a fatal error getting fired?

Comment: Sorry failed when writing post its updated

Comment: Did you verify the value of `$max` in the ServerSide function is actually 100 (using var_dump for example)? The variable `$length` in your controller is populated directly from the requests query parameter "length", I guess?

Comment: yes its that, i have verify, and i have replace $max by '100', always same problem :/.